# I am trying to identify who made my bike

Tags: identify-this-bike, vintage, germany, schwinn

We bought this bike locally via an auction. The front hub appears to say "made in Germany" and has a cloverleaf symbol. One pedal is Schwinn, front tire is a Spitfire, Rear is a Lowell. Seat is a Troxel. When I checked the serial # on a Schwinn site it said it was a Schwinn from August 1957. I doubt that as others have said it is not one of their models. The unique twin top tube throws me off as does the ridged front fender. My guess was it is an Evans? Serial # is 0030102. Both rims are white.

[image: Photograph of bike as described above.]

Comment: Not an expert but my read is that it's probably not any American brand, Schwinn or otherwise, because few American bikes like this have any BB shell but American/OPC. I think your answer is going to lay in finding a company that did BB shell joints like that along with the massive one-piece downtube/seattube, both of which are extremely distinctive.

Comment: Cobbled together Frankenbike from bits & pieces left and right?

Comment: It's a schwinn rear rack, anyway. It's handsome, not any kind of "frankenbike" but it's always hard to say with bikes of this age how much is original. Even if you do learn the maker (which may be hidden under the paint) you won't gain very much.

Comment: Nathan, what is a BB shell joint? Also, the front hub says "made in germany" and there is a clover symbol. One peddle is Union which is German as well. I am also wondering who did a ridged front fender and that rack?

Comment: @NathanKnutson - The cottered crank would not be surprising on an up-scale US bike from the 50s & 60s.

Comment: The vane on the front fender and the doubled top tube are not surprising for a bike of the era.

Comment: Look at how the bottom bracket area comes together with the downtube and seat tube compared to most bikes. It's pretty unusual. Little or no mitering. The way the dt and st are the same tube is also unusual.

Comment: @NathanKnutson - Fairly normal for a "girl's bike" of the era.

Comment: If you can find a picture of another bike with a similar arrangement, with no or almost no mitering around the shell and a teeny weld or braze in its place, you probably will have found a picture of another bike by the same maker.

Comment: I found the tube that goes up to the seat to be unique, how it curves.  Also the double top tub. The main sprocket appears to be a Schwinn type.That is a good way to describe the front fender, a vane, or ridge. Thank you for all of the feedback!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a bike with the same down tube/seat tube arrangement:

[image: Here is a bike with the same down tube/seat tube arrangement]

Here is a bike with the same top tube arrangement, and it looks like it might have the same down tube/seat tube arrangement:

[image: Here is a bike with the same top tube arrangement, and it looks like it might have the same down tube/seat tube arrangement]